# Trying to run bash command in windows /usr/bin/env: ‘php’: Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel

[image]

This is my command that I've made but I get an error , I'm on WIN10

Comment: did you try with sudo ?

Comment: /usr/bin/sudo: /usr/bin/sudo: cannot execute binary file

Answer (score 1):

The error says that the user account that tries to run the command on that system has not the permissions / rights to do so. Please check, what user is trying to run that command and either give appropriate rights or create / change the permissions on that file.